# How to add shadow to parts of UIImage which is not transparent?

Tags: ios, swift, opencv

I have a little code in swift for drawing on a UIImageView (it creates a UIImage from the drawing). I would like to add shadow after the image is finished to the parts where there's content.

So if a user draws only a line, and adds shadow, it applies to that line.

I have no idea how to do that, can layers do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Call `CGContextSetShadow` before drawing the line.

Comment: I would like to add shadow after the line is there and the image is done. There is a button for adding shadow to the existing image.

Comment: Does opencv has anything that would be handy for me?